# Como obter valor dos checkbox selecionados

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Estou desenvolvendo um site que tem um filtro de busca por bairros, onde a pessoa seleciona em checkbox os bairros. Aí preciso pegar o valores que estão checados e jogar em um texto (ex: Bairros selecionados: Brooklin, Campo Belo)

Os checkbox estão assim (é uma lista com dezenas de bairros):

```
<div class="span3">
<input type="checkbox" value="43" name="bairro[]" id="bairro0">&nbsp; Aclimação
</div>
<div class="span3">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="bairro[]" id="bairro1">&nbsp; Alto da Boa Vista
</div>
<div class="span3">
<input type="checkbox" value="48" name="bairro[]" id="bairro2">&nbsp; Alto da Lapa
</div>
```

Se possível pegar já o nome do bairro, caso não dê posso pegar só o valor do checkbox e fazer uma consulta usando mysql e php para trazer o nome.

Quando a pessoa aplica o filtro e dá OK, a página já carrega com os campos selecionados.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'");
var selecionados = '';
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  if (els[i].checked) {
    selecionados += els[i].nextSibling.nodeValue + ',';
    document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML = selecionados.substring(0, selecionados.length - 1);;
  }

  els[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (this.checked)
      selecionados += this.nextSibling.nodeValue + ',';
    document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML = selecionados.substring(0, selecionados.length - 1);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="span3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="43" name="bairro[]" id="bairro0">&nbsp; Aclimação</input>
</div>
<div class="span3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="bairro[]" id="bairro1">&nbsp; Alto da Boa Vista</input>
</div>
<div class="span3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="48" name="bairro[]" id="bairro2" checked>&nbsp; Alto da Lapa</input>
</div>
<br>Selecionados:
<label id="sel"></label>
```

Comment: Quase isso, a única modificação, como faço para ele logo no começo já trazer só quem está selecionado? por exemplo alto da lapa já estar checked e ele trazer o valor Alto da lapa

Comment: PERFEITO!!! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Troque o name do seus inputs para:

```
name="bairro"
```

E tente isso:

```
$(function () {
    $('.span3').click(function () {
        var checkValues = $('input[name=bairro]:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).parent().text();
        }).get();
        //do something with your checkValues array
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja desta forma, gerando um link para pesquisa com `$_GET`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){             
  $("#test").click(function(){           
  var testval = [];
     $('.span3:checked').each(function() {
       testval.push($(this).val());
     });
    document.getElementById("bairro").text = "http://teste.com/?bairro="+testval;
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  
  <div class="span3">
<input class="span3" type="checkbox" value="43" name="bairro[]" id="bairro0">&nbsp; Aclimação
</div>
<div class="span3">
<input class="span3" type="checkbox" value="2" name="bairro[]" id="bairro1">&nbsp; Alto da Boa Vista
</div>
<div class="span3">
<input class="span3" type="checkbox" value="48" name="bairro[]" id="bairro2">&nbsp; Alto da Lapa
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="test">Test</a></div>
</br>
<a href="#" id="bairro"> </a>
```

Desta forma irá listar todos os itens selecionados e colocar como uma parâmetro na URL.